# Refresh data table after edit row in to database

Tags: html, sql-server, angular, rxjs, nestjs

I have data table in the manage.component.html (portion of code):

```
<table
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-lg"
    [mfData]="links$ | async"
    #mf="mfDataTable"
    [mfRowsOnPage]="10">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 5%">
              <mfDefaultSorter by="id" #sortId>
                ID
                <span *ngIf="sortId.isSortedByMeAsc" class="cil-arrow-top" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span *ngIf="sortId.isSortedByMeDesc" class="cil-arrow-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 50%">
              <mfDefaultSorter by="linkCategory" #sortCategory>
                Category
                <span *ngIf="sortCategory.isSortedByMeAsc" class="cil-arrow-top" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span
                  *ngIf="sortCategory.isSortedByMeDesc"
                  class="cil-arrow-bottom"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
              </mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 50%"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let link of mf.data">
            <td>{{ link.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ link.linkCategory }}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 btn-edit" (click)="editLink(link.id)">
                Edit
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-2 btn-delete" (click)="deleteLink(link.id)">
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="9">
              <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5, 10, 15]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

I have service for manage.component with **links$** Observable as well:

```
export class ManageService {
  private _links$ = new BehaviorSubject<model.Link[]>([]);
  private _query$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  links$: Observable<model.Link[]>;
  query$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.refreshLinks();
    this.links$ = combineLatest([this._links$, this._query$]).pipe(
      map(([links, query]) => links.filter(link => link.linkName.toLowerCase().includes(query)))
    );
  }
  getLinks(): Observable<model.Link[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<model.Link[]>('/api/links');
  }
  findLink(query: string) {
    this._query$.next(query);
  }
  private refreshLinks() {
    this.getLinks().subscribe(links => {
      this._links$.next(links);
    });
  }
}
```

For know everything is working correctly. I see table with data and buttons in every row.
I've prepared new edit.component for edit button:

- form in HTML with data prefilled
- scss styles
- submit button which who is calling createLink method as below (method from edit.service):

  ```
  public createLink() {
       this.link.id = parseInt(this.linkId);
       this.service.createLink(this.link).subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
         this.router.navigate(['/links/manage']);
       });
       this.publishModal.hide();
     }
  ```

edit.service.ts (portion of code):

```
  createLink(link: model.Link): Observable<model.Link> {
    return this.httpClient.post<model.Link>('/api/createLink', link, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

My changed data are sending to database correctly and after submit I have newer data in DB and I'm navigate back to table with whole links.
I see table of links$ but I have to refresh the browser to see updated rows as well.
In `console.log(res);` I see updated object, in DB I see it also but I don't see them on the screen.
What's wrong?

Comment: Your are using links$ in your template to display data. this.links$ is assigned in constructor only. when you call createLink method from component you need to assign/retrigger the logic for this.links$.

Comment: What's the best option to do it? And is'it a good practice ?

Comment: you can create a method and assign links$ in that method and call it wherever you need.